# sql server raiseerror with numeric parameter

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @institution varchar(10) = 'a', @num numeric(10,1) = 200.1
RAISERROR ('Start of strength_senior_update, @institution = %s', 0, 1,
        @institution);
RAISERROR ('Start of strength_senior_update, @institution = %s, @num=%s', 0, 1,
        @institution,@num);
```

the first RAISEERROR show expect result

> Start of strength_senior_update, @institution = a

but the second RAISEERROR return error as below

> The data type of substitution parameter 2 does not match the expected
> type of the format specification.

anyway, there is no format specification for numeric datatype, so how to use raiseerror with numeric parameter? must declare a varchar variable and then cast the @num to that varchar variable first?

2. if so trouble, why not I use print instead?

Comment: Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), if you used `%s` it would expects a varchar. There are only limited supported type. For the second parameter, you may convert to `varchar` before passing in

Comment: It would be simpler to just build your error message using `concat` you can use any data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no format specification for numeric datatype, so how to use
> raiseerror with numeric parameter? must declare a varchar variable and
> then cast the @num to that varchar variable first?

Correct, `RAISERROR` format specifications are limited so the work-around is to assign formatted message text to a variable for use with `RAISERROR`. The below example gleaned from the comments uses `CONCAT` (to convert NULL values to empty strings) and `FORMAT` to display the numeric value in the format of your choosing.

```
DECLARE @institution varchar(10) = 'a', @num numeric(10,1) = 200.1, @message varchar(2047);
SET @message = CONCAT('Start of strength_senior_update, @institution = '
    , @institution
    , ', @num='
    , FORMAT(@num, '0.0')
    );
RAISERROR (@message, 0, 1);
```

> if so trouble, why not I use print instead?

There is no value in using `RAISERROR` instead of `PRINT` for severity zero informational messages unless you want to use the `NOWAIT` option or substitution parameters. `PRINT` allows you to specify the message expression directly without the need to assign to variable:

```
DECLARE @institution varchar(10) = 'a', @num numeric(10,1) = 200.1;
PRINT CONCAT('Start of strength_senior_update, @institution = '
    , @institution
    , ', @num='
    , FORMAT(@num, '0.0')
    );
```

Comment: in sql server documentation, nowait option will Sends messages immediately to the client. but I find it still wait until the stored procedure or job calling the stored procedure is finished....why?
e.g. if I call raiseerror with nowait option and then write a infinite loop, the raiseerror message is never outputted to console, why?

Comment: @user1169587, it's up to the client app code to show the messages immediately. This shows the messages immediately when run from an SSMS query window: `WHILE 1=1 BEGIN RAISERROR('example',0,0) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; END;`